# what is the recommended system requirement for using eclipse and maven plugin?

Tags: performance, eclipse, ide, system, m2eclipse

I am wondering what is the recommended system requirement for using eclipse and m2eclipse plugin. I am using E8400 and 4Gb ram currently. Nearly every time I changed something in the pom.xml the eclipse IDE would hang for a while (about 1-3 minutes) before it finished. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is not normal.

I do all my development on a laptop with 4GB of RAM and I am able to run Eclipse + M2Eclipse + Tomcat + Flex/Flash + MySQL, etc.  I change my POMs (8 of them in one project) constantly and it usually never takes more than a few seconds.

That said, depending on the size of your dependency tree it can take a while to download all the dependencies to your local machine.  You can find out what is happening by opening the console view in Eclipse and selecting the Maven console within it.  Check it out and report back, perhaps there will be a clue as to some other problem.